# How do I get html from textedit to appear in Chrome?

Tags: html, textedit

I'm brand new to html so please bear with me...
I am trying to use textedit on mac to write html but it wont appear properly in chrome when I open the file.

I typed the following into text edit, saved as index.html file then when I open with chrome it appears exactly as it has been written with all the tags showing...what am I doing wrong? The code is a straight copy from W3schools so I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the code so must be the way I am managing the files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>My First Heading</h1>

        <p>My first paragraph.</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You go to it in file explorer and right click and choose open with chrome?

Comment: Works fine for me, the one thing I can think of would be it isn't saved as an html document and just is a txt file or something.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're not using plain text mode. According to https://support.apple.com/guide/textedit/work-with-html-documents-txted0b6cd61/mac:

**Create an HTML file**

1. In the TextEdit app  on your Mac, choose File > New, then choose Format > Make Plain Text.
2. Enter the HTML code.
3. Choose File > Save, type a name followed by the extension .html (for example, enter index.html), then click Save.
4. When prompted about the extension to use, click “Use .html.”

See also https://www.lifewire.com/edit-html-with-textedit-3469900 and https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-configure-textedit-for-coding-html--mac-44786